# JSON.NET Deserialize - Can't figure out the classes?

Tags: .net, json, json.net

Here's the JSON:

```
{
  "status": "live",
  "responses": 10,
  "questions": {
    "ZuGnqOpd3w": {
       "title": "Sample Title",
       "type": "threed-grid",
       "id": "ZuGnqOpd3w",
       "label": "Sample Label."
       }
     } 
 }
```

And the classes;

```
Public Class Survey
    Public Property status As String

    Public Property responses As Integer

    Public Property questions() As jQuestion()

End Class

Public Class jQuestion
    Public Property Title as String 
    ......
End Class
```

When I try to deserialize it I get the following error:
Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'jQuestion[]'.

Can someone help me structure my classes correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not very familiar with json.net, it looks like you `json` object is formatted incorrectly based on your classes. Since `Questions` is an array, the value in `json` should be surrounded in square brackets `[]`

```
{
  "status": "live",
  "responses": 10,
  "questions": [
       {
        "title": "Sample Title",
        "type": "threed-grid",
        "id": "ZuGnqOpd3w",
        "label": "Sample Label."
       },
       {
        "title": "Sample Title 2",
        "type": "threed-grid 2",
        "id": "ZuGnqOpd3w 2",
        "label": "Sample Label. 2"
       }
     ] 
 }
```

In future when validating the `json` format you are trying to deserialize, you could cheat by creating your objects in .net and then see what they look like when you serialize them using json.net.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm deserializing the JSON response from an online Survey Provider so I have no control over how the JSON is structured unfortunately.

Comment: @Tom Sorry I do not know of an OOB way of doing that. Because the `questions` array is not depicted with square brackets, I think you'll need to get it into proper `json` format first in a manual process. I'd be interested in knowing you end solution. Cheers!